# How to get result from another context when using react navigation 5 without redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Package Version:

```
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.15",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
```

I'm using react navigation 5 which have implement no switch navigator. Below are my screen flow:-

```
naviContainer.js
    ├── SplashScreen.js
    ├── LoginScreen.js
    └── BottomTabScreen.js
```

**SplashScreen.js** flow

1. Read `AsyncStorage` to get token if available
2. Check connection with web domain
3. Get configuration value from REST Api
4. If #1 resolve, validate token with REST Api to receive user information token and **resolve** promise. Else, **reject**

```
export const SplashScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
async function LoadInitialComponent() {}
useEffect(() => {
    setProgressText('Initializing component...');
    AppGlobal.constRESTful = serverDomain + 'api/store';
    if (isRendered) {
        LoadInitialComponent()
            .then(response => {
                /// Token available and splash is done. Go to BottomTabScreen
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                /// Token unavailable and splash is done. Go to LoginScreen
            });
    }
    return () => {
        isRendered = false;
    }
}, []);
return (
<View/>
)
}
```

**NavigationContainer.js** from tutorial [Authentication Setup](https://learn.handlebarlabs.com/courses/804752/lectures/14646920)

```
const StackApp = createStackNavigator();
export const StackNavigator = () => {
  const [IsLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);
  const [IsLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(!IsLoading);
      setIsLoggedIn(false);
    }, 1500);
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {IsLoading === true
        ? (
          <SplashScreen />
        )
        : IsLoggedIn === true
          ? (
            <StackApp.Screen name='Dashboard' component={NavigatorDashboard} />
          )
          : (
            <StackApp.Screen name='Login' component={NavigatorLogin} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          )
      }
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

> **How do I get value from SplashScreen.js whether the it has finish loading and if the token is acquire or not?**

If I need `IsFinishLoading` from SplashScreen and `IsLoggedIn` based from Token availability, how should I declare to return from SplashScreen and how do I wait and read the SplashScreen return value? Current is follow from tutorial which using setTimeout as part of tutorial purposes.

I have try to find some of the way to do it, but mostly show using `redux`. I'm not using redux so I have no idea how to achieve this. Some of the question regarding navigation conditional in navigation 5 still unanswered.

I also have read on React site [Authentication Flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) written as below but it get the isSignedIn from `SignInScreen` is using reducer too.

```
isSignedIn ? (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a switch navigator using the context.
There maybe multiple options but this is how i would do it.

First think of your splash screen as a component and not a screen, then you can simply do the async call check and update the context from there and you can conditionally render the stack using RN5.

Here we have a context and the splash screen updates the context, you wont need redux or anything here. We show the splash screen or the navigation based on the context.
If you really want to go with a screen for splashscreen you can modify to have something like an enum in context and show the screen based on that using multiple conditions. (Like 1-> Splash, 2-> Home 3->Login)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const AppContext = React.createContext();

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details... again"
        onPress={() => navigation.push('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function SplashScreen() {
  const { setAppState } = React.useContext(AppContext);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    //Check async storage
    setAppState({ isLoggedIn: true });
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Welcome Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  const [appState, setAppState] = React.useState({});
  const state = { appState, setAppState };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={state}>
      {appState.isLoggedIn ? (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      ) : (
        <SplashScreen />
      )}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can checkout the sample in the snack as well
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/sampleswitch

Comment: if together with `HomeScreen` there is bottom tab with `ProfileScreen` that have button Logout, which it component is on another file, can it be use as same like AppContext? Or everything must be put into App.js like your snack?

Comment: yes you can put the context in a separate file and export it and use it in the logout with useContext and it would work, I did like this as its easy to put as an answer

Comment: great idea. have done it, and it can be use by any imported file

Comment: yep thats the best part of using context :)